# Deleting user posts using a delete button

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a table with the following fields: `wall_posts`, `group_id`, `id`, and `user_id`.

`wall_posts` is user entries, `group_id` is imported from another table and is just a unique group id, `id` is just a simple counter, and `user_id` gets the user id from the session.

My code gets rid of all the `wall_posts` if you press the delete button by comparing the user id to the user in session. Now I do not want to redirect to another php page to delete. So using the URL is just not an option. Right now this cod just deletes the newest posts. For example if I click on the delete button on a post with id=10 and the last post has an id=12. It just deletes the post with the id=12 and then pressing the delete button again results in deleting the post with id=11 and so on. I guess a good example of what I'm trying to do would be how you delete a news feed or a comment on your facebook page.

Here is the code:

```
    if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $current_user = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM group_posts");
    while ($delete = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $group_user_id = $delete['user_id'];
        $post_id = $delete['id'];
    }
    if ($current_user == $group_user_id) {
    $sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM group_posts WHERE id = %d", $post_id);
    mysql_query($sql);
    }

}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want. Could you be more specific about the actual and the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

sending a simple ajax post request you can achieve exactly what you want. cookies are sent on ajax, so $_SESSION will be normally accesible

using jquery to abbreviate ajax:

```
$('#btnDelete').click(function(){$.post('#',{delete:1});});
```

add a third paremeter to $.post() to do something after php ends

respectly to delete all the records, just move the second if block inside the while block. i'd change the whole proccess to just

```
mysql_query("delete from group_posts where user_id= ".$current_user);
```

Comment: I have just started using PHP and I dont know much about jquery. Do you think you can collaborate on  the $('#btnDelete').click(function(){$.post('#',{delete:1});}); function or if there are any tutorials on it, can you guide me to it? THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library you add to your html. jquery.com has a lot of info, and there are a lot of tutorials on the internet too.

Answer (score 0):

So I got it right, in addition to what Einacio said, you doing this asynchronously does not mean anything but calling the page without actually going to that page in a browser.

So your PHP page which deletes the entries in the database is just the same page as usual, doing it's thing. The difference is how yo call it - in this case with the function Einacio posted. This piece of Javascript calls the page, submits a parameter and gives you the response if any. Go to www.jquery.com and search for the AJAX examples and try them out. It's not that difficult.